# CSS: vertical tabs with a content start at the same height level as active tab

Tags: html, css

Well i never thought i'll go to stackoverflow with css problem, But i feel really puzzled with this structure.

As you may see on the picture there is a three tabs, and a content on the same height level. When i choose the next one, the content for it opens as shown on picture.

Now do not pay attention on the graph, lets say it is just a text. But this part should be responsive. Tab and features section have to stay fixed.   by the way the whole structure is wrapped with

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-2"></div>
```

[image: tab a active]

[image: Tab b active]

My first idea was just to wrap the tab and its section in div, but in this case not active tabs will be hidden under the active div and not be clickable.

Any idea how to do this??

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you thought of using jQuery vertical tabs? http://jsfiddle.net/tj_vantoll/nn2Qw/

Comment: What do you think of this ? http://codepen.io/sodawillow/pen/MYJvYb